# Java pattern: regexp - Allow few special character in between character

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to allow some character through regular expression. I want to allow word with special character like ( - _ & spaces) in between the character. Also i am allowing number in a word along with letter.

Valid:

```
a_B
a_b
a b
a B
a_btest_psom
a-B
a43 b
a43_c
```

Invalid:

```
a_
_a
a-
a_b_
a_B_
a_b-
a_btest_psom_ (at end only special character)
43 b (starting with number)
43_c (starting with number)
434343 (only numbers)
```

Code:

```java
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

public static final String PATTERN="^[a-zA-Z0-9 _-]*$"; 
@Pattern(regexp = PATTERN)
private String companyName;
```

Using above code, I am not able to achieve as per my expectation. Can you help me on this?

Comment: Is `a` (one character) or `a- b` (adjacent specials inside) or `a1` (ending in digit) valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:[ _-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9ZsXr9/2)

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*` - a letter and then zero or more letters or digits
- `(?:[ _-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - zero or more sequences of a space/`_`/`-` and then one or more letters or digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: (be aware that `^` and `$` actually mean start and end of line if MULTILINE is active [and not needed for `matches`])

Answer (score 1):

Please try this regex.

^[a-zA-Z][A-Za-z0-9 ()/]*$

You can add whatever special character you want in your regex. Modify it as per your requirement.

Comment: Here what you have added special character to allow?

Comment: I have to use only () in my input filed. So, this regex will solve my problem. You can also add any special character followed by / in your custom regex.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding in this in the begining `[a-zA-Z]` and at the end `[a-zA-Z0-9]` should work.

`^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 _-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$` that means that first char should be a character and the last char should be a character or a number.

Use this: `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 _-]*[a-zA-Z]$` if it doesnt have to finish with a number.